# Pure text in tkinter without any label

Tags: python, tkinter, text, label

Hi I want to make some kind of a pomodoro application, and I want the clock to be printed in the middle of window without any label just pure text (numbers changing each second).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT
I found answer I just should use label and then change it colour so I can match with window and of course also change text colour so I anyone could read it.
The answer is such obvious, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: You can't have text without a `Label`/`Canvas`/another widget. Why do you not want the label?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from a "pure text" that isn't available in a label?

Comment: You can write text on a canvas or in a text widget.

Comment: there is approximately one way to write some text in `tkinter` without using any widgets (except `Tk`), that is to change the title of the window, obviously it won't be centered in the middle of the window (more of like in the middle of title bar) but you won't need any other widgets. Also you can change the text of a `Label` too, so it is hard to understand why you don't want to use any widgets, also provide a [mre] of what you have tried already

Comment: @Matiiss Never thought about it like that :D. Now my comment has been proven wrong...

Comment: I know should use labels such as text or entry. But the problem is I want my window black and that way I will havet white rectangle in the middle of black window which I consider ugly and I wanted to know if there is any possibility that I could do it without any label and now I know I can't. Thank you guys for your effort.

Comment: @Kyle2115 then change the background color of the label to match the background color of the window.